# Performance problems when parsing large vectors in QML using Repeater

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qml

I'm parsing a list of ~4000 emojis from a C++ QAbstractListModel subclass using Repeatables.

The emojis are being collected in a class called `EmojiList`:

**emojilist.h**

```cpp
#include <QVector>

class EmojiList {
public:

    struct EmojiData {
        EmojiData(const QString& _code, const QString& _shortname, const QString& _category) :
            code(_code),
            shortname(_shortname),
            category(_category)
        {}

        QString code;
        QString shortname;
        QString category;
    };

    static const QVector<EmojiData>& list();

private:
    QVector<EmojiData> emojiList;

    void parseFromFile();
};
```

**emojilist.cpp**

```cpp
#include "emojilist.h"

#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

const QVector<EmojiList::EmojiData>& EmojiList::list()
{
    static EmojiList list;

    if (list.emojiList.isEmpty()) {
        list.parseFromFile();
    }

    return list.emojiList;
}

void EmojiList::parseFromFile()
{
    QFile emojiResource { ":/media/new_emoji.list" };

    if (emojiResource.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in { &emojiResource };

        while (!in.atEnd()) {
            QStringList line { in.readLine().split(',') };
            emojiList.append({ line.at(0), line.at(1), line.at(2) });
        }
    }

    emojiResource.close();
}
```

Then, the data is being retrieved in the `QAbstractListModel` subclass `EmojiListModel`:

**emojilistmodel.cpp**

```cpp
QVariant EmojiListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (_emojiMap.isEmpty() || !index.isValid() || index.row() > _emojiMap.size()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    switch (role) {
    case EmojiName:
        return _emojiMap.at(index.row()).shortname;
    case Emoji:
        return _emojiMap.at(index.row()).code;
    case EmojiCategory: {
        return _emojiMap.at(index.row()).category;
    }
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

On the front-end side, I'm displaying the model data using a Repeater:

**EmojiWindow.qml**

```
ScrollView {
    // ...
    clip: true

    GridLayout {
        id: emojiGridView
        // ...

        Repeater {
            id: emojiContainer
            model: EmojiListModel {
                id: emojiListModel
                objectName: "emojiListModel"
            }

            Rectangle {
                // ...
                property string delegateEmojiName: emojiName

                Text {
                    id: emojiIcon
                    text: emoji
                    // ...
                }

                MouseArea {
                    // ...
                    onClicked: messageField.text += emojiIcon.text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when starting the application, it takes **about 5 minutes to create all Repeater delegates** to construct and thus for the whole application to start up.

**How can I optimize performance in my QML file to load about 4000 emojis on startup? Is there some way to lazy-load the data to be displayed?**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are all 4000 emoji visible at one time? If not, I recommend something like a GridView instead of a GridLayout/Repeater. A GridView is smart enough to only create enough delegates as it needs for what's currently visible.

Comment: @JarMan using a GridView fastens the startup speed, however it makes the application itself super slow and barely usable, plus, I am getting at least 5 exceptions (`Exception at 0x7ffa39364f69, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in dwrite!DWriteCreateFactory`).

Comment: Weird. I don't know why that would be. You could also try simply replacing the Repeater with an [Instantiator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-instantiator.html), and then setting its `asynchronous` property to true.

Comment: @JarMan replacing `Repeater` with `Instantiator`, I don't get any output. I just tried it with a blank project only using `model: 30` and with `Repeater` I see 30 rectangles but when using `Instantiator` I won't see any output.

Comment: Oh, that's probably because with an Instantiator, the created objects don't automatically know who their parent object are. Inside your Rectangle delegate add this: `parent: emojiGridView`.

Comment: @JarMan yes, thanks, that solved it and it looks like this would work, however I got back to testing GridView for my purposes, will let you know what turned out to be the most useful one.